# Linode Deban Linux + Nginx + unicorn_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, debian, unicorn

I'm a new Linode/Linux user running Debian 6. I'm trying to get my Unicorn server to start at boot, but for some reason it is not, and I'm not able to track down any error message. Nginx is starting fine, and I have a multi-user RVM install. My gut feeling is that is has something to do with RVM. This is my `unicorn_init.sh` file in `/rails/todo`, and there's a symlink to it at `/etc/init.d/unicorn`:

```
# unicorn_init.sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/rails/todo
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn_rails -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
GEM_HOME="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global"
action="$1"
set -u

old_id="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1
export GEM_HOME=$GEM_HOME

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $old_pid && kill -$1 `cat $old_pid`
}

case $action in
  start)
    sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
    su -c "$CMD" - root
    ;;
  stop)
    sig QUIT && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  force-stop)
    sig TERM && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  restart|reload)
    sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
    su -c "$CMD" - root
    ;;
  upgrade)
    if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
    then
      n=$TIMEOUT
      while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
      do
        printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
      done
      echo

      if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
      then
        echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
        exit 1
      fi
      exit 0
    fi
    echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
    su -c "$CMD" - root
    ;;
  reopen-logs)
    sig USR1
    ;;
  *)
    echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

I'm 99% of the way to getting my setup working—any advice would be much appreciated.

Here is the output of `$ update-rc.d unicorn defaults`:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'unicorn' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service nginx and unicorn if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service unicorn at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service nginx at depth 1
insserv: Stopping unicorn depends on nginx and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header

The start of your file looks like:

```
# unicorn_init.sh
#!/bin/sh
```

The shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) MUST be the very first line of the file.

I can't comment on the loop-detection messages as I haven't ever seen 'em before.  It's possible something you say in /etc/init.d/nginx is expressing dependency on unicorn, but I don't see anything in the unicorn init which expresses a dependency on nginx, so the loop isn't clear.

> insserv: warning: script 'unicorn' missing LSB tags and overrides

You should add LSB info to your init script http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: It was the missing LSB info that was the problem. That first comment was just for this post—I should have noted that.